# How can I update a driver without device manager OR track down a device from the driver's filename?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers

If I know the file name of a driver, e.g. `somenic.sys`, or have the `.inf` file, how can track down the device this driver is attached to in Device manager?

Alternatively how can I update (as in downgrade) this driver without going through Device manager?

OS=Win 10

---

Ran into an issue where downgrading a driver was required, but the program responsible messed things up, necessitating manual intervention.

- Showing hidden devices in Device manager was not helpful. There are too many to check by hand.
- Using "Install" from the inf file context yielded no result.
- The file in `c:\windows\system32\drivers` is obviously locked down by the system. I don't know how to remove it or if that would be helpful. I don't know what other copies there might be (I know many of the files there are hardlinked, though this one was not.)

Comment: The contents of the inf file will at least tell you the name of the device you are linking for in Device Manager. Using "install" on the information only copies the driver to where it needs to be for the system to use it if the device is plugged in, it "installs" the files, not the actual device. According to https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/find-replace-outdated-windows-drivers/ `driverquery` might also resolve a name like `somenic` to a worthwhile name.

Comment: There was nothing matching in the inf. I suppose just based on the number of files it is highly likely not all drivers have an associated device. `driverquery` doesn't resolve to anything that wasn't already in the inf file. However some clues led to find out it is something called an "NDIS filter driver". And `netcfg -s n` lists it as a "Network service". The command can also be used to remove this component, tho I am unable to test right now. I suppose this means there is no universal answer to this question (or perhaps one would be very long).